# How to fix regular blackout of Touch Bar?

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, touch-bar

I have a 13-inch 2017 MacBook Pro (Intel Core i5) with a Touch Bar. I've noticed, that it occasionally disappears, and then after a few days re-appears.

It is not a hardware problem, as [killing the touch bar server](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254759141?sortBy=best) is affecting the Touch Bar: The buttons come back in a 'grayed out' colouring, but they are not affected by touch sensory. Unsure if the following information may be relevant: My behaviour, when I go off, is to close the lid of the computer overnight. I don't leave my computer powered at 100% battery and never let it run down to 0%. (If the Touch Bar has its' own battery, it *should* always be powered.)

Another observation I've made is, that it seems to be most of the time browser (Chrome) - or more specifically YouTube related, but it also once happened when I did not have the browser open.

Usually the touch bar re-appears the next day. The question is, why does this happen, and what options do I have on preventing it, without sacrificing quality of life (for example, without always turning off Mac)?

Comment: To clarify:  It dies (fades out) (1) whilst the Mac is in use, or  (2) after you've put it to sleep after watching a YouTube video, and then when you wake the Mac, the touchbar has died..? Possibly unrelated, but I've killed a few older Macs (or rather the GPUs) by running an HD video, causing the Mac to heat and then putting it to sleep immediately (maybe even during video playback), *without letting it cool down first* (i.e. sleep caused the fans to stop)- so maybe heat related due to video playback?. Also, the TouchBar reappears (1) whilst Mac is on, or (2) upon waking up?

Comment: There could be many issues to manifest like this, so perhaps take it to a repair shop to get it evaluated properly.

Comment: The Touchbar is a separate display driven by the T2 chip and running BridgeOS. It is very likely a hardware issue; it’s not prudent to rule out hardware without proper diagnostics.  I’m hesitant to make a sight unseen diagnosis, but based on my experience with these models MacBook Pro, I wouldn’t be surprised if you needed to replace the TB assembly

Comment: @Greenonline mostly after I re-open the lid, the touch bar is black, I do play videos in the background, but during their stream, the touchbar may be slow, but never disappears. I don't think there's opportunity for the mac to properly cool, before I close the lid, that may be right. (2): One day Touch Bar disappears, after a few days, I open the lid, and their magically back.

Comment: In recent days, being completely off YouTube, I noticed the Touch Bar not dieing. Seems to be video-related.

Comment: It happened just now. Closed the lid, no video was played, opened the lid, and the display is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, performing an NVRAM (https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204063) and/or SMC reset (https://support.apple.com/en-us/102605) helps in such cases.
If the issue persists and still annoys you, re-installing macOS also re-installs required software components to address the touch bar.

Comment: Don’t do this!  First, there’s nothing in NVRAM related to this condition.  NVRAM holds **pre**-boot environment values, not runtime.  Secondly, reinstalling macOS does nothing but waste time.  A much better option  is to boot into Safe Mode which will disable all 3rd party apps and kexts leaving a clean macOS to see if the issue is OS related.